# Why MongoDB subdocument expiration removes parent document?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema, subdocument

I use mongoose 5 and have a schemas like this:

user.js

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const GeoData = require('./geodata');

const UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  createdAt: {
    type: Date,
    default: Date.now()
  },
  geodata: GeoData
});

UserSchema.index({ deviceToken: 1 }, { unique: true });

module.exports = UserSchema;
```

geodata.js

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const c2p = require('circle-to-polygon');

const GeoDataSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  location: {
    coordinates: [Number],
    type: {
      type: String
    }
  },
  createdAt: {
    type: Date,
    default: Date.now()
  },
  expireAt: {
    type: Date,
    default: new Date().setHours(12,0,0,0)
  }
});

GeoDataSchema.index({ location: "2dsphere", bounds: "2dsphere" });
GeoDataSchema.index({ 'expireAt': 1 }, { expireAfterSeconds: 0 });

module.exports = GeoDataSchema;
```

Let's say the `geodata` subdocument is added to the parent `user` document with expiration set to 12:00:00 local time by default.
Unfortunately this removes parent `user` with subdocument `geodata` instead of removing `geodata` only as I would expect.

Is this normal behavior or am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A TTL index always works on a root document, never on individual subdocuments or other parts of a document.

According to the [documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/expire-data/):

> A special TTL index property supports the implementation of TTL
>   collections. The TTL feature relies on a background thread in mongod
>   that reads the date-typed values in the index and removes expired
>   documents from the collection.

Comment: Thanks - the word I missed was `documents`. Anyway it would be really neat if it were implemented in the future. Now I have to write a cron job to iterate and find outdated docs or move `geodata` to its own collection and add its own TTL index.

Comment: You could file a feature request?

Comment: Certainly will do!